# Undefined array.length returns true not false

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working through the MDN JavaScript documentation and in one of the beginner exercises it claims that: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Evaluating_variables)

The undefined value behaves as false when used in a boolean context.

```
var myArray = [];
if (!myArray[0]) myFunction();
```

However, my brain being simple can't work with opposites in an if statement. Therefore I re-wrote it using the .length function:

```js
var myArray = [];
if(myArray.length === 1) {
  console.log("How?");
} else {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}
```

What I was expecting was Hello World! to be printed because the Array is undefined and should return false however it is returning 1.

Any explanation as to why this is happening would be great!

Comment: The code outputs `Hello World!`. Also I think you mean empty array and not undefined.

Comment: The array is not undefined, it is empty, and it will return Hello World!

Comment: You are wrong, array is not undefined as you initialized it with **var myArray = []**

Comment: Your two statements are doing different things, the first is testing against the first item in the array (`undefined`), the second is testing against the number of items in the array (`0`). What exactly are you attempting?

Comment: [This might be useful to understand equality in JS](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/). But other than that, I can't reproduce the issue. I've edited the code into a runnable snippet, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the test `myArray.length === 1` to evaluate to `true` the array must contain **exactly** one element. But you didn't put anything in there so the test failed and `Hello World!` was printed.

Think of an array as a container.

```
var myArray; // is undefined

var myArray = [] // is NOT undefined
```

`var myArray = []` is empty but it is a valid array.

Therefore, using `.length`, a better test would have been:

```
if (myArray.length === 0)
```

Then `How?` would have been printed.

Because there is nothing in your array, the length is 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re in doubts debugging check with console output or inspect the variables/create you watch.

```js
var myArray = [];
console.log(!myArray);
console.log(!myArray[0]);

printIt(myArray.length === 0)
printIt(myArray.length === 1)

function printIt(ok) { 
  if(ok) { console.log("Ok."); }
  else { console.log("Not ok."); } 
}
```

If you’re about to check if array is empty you should express you desire by code, so:

```
if(array.length === 0) …
```

If you’re about to check if variable is declared …

```js
var array;
console.log(!array);

array = [];
console.log(!array);

console.log(Array.isArray(array));

let u = "u";
console.log(Array.isArray(u));
```

If you need to aware of both …

```js
var array;
//console.log(array.length);

array = [];

if(array && Array.isArray(array) && array.length === 0) { array.push("Hi!"); console.log(array[0]);}

let w = "w";
if(w && Array.isArray(w)) { console.log(w);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [];
if (!myArray[0]) myFunction();
```

`myArray[0]` - In this array initialization default zero will take 1.

`if(myArray.length === 1)` - In this line, it will return to get the opposite result of the initialization. So, it printed to be 1.